# Databricks find cell header from command id?

Tags: logging, databricks

I'm playing around with logging in databricks and trying to handle errors. When I get an uncaught error I can get an output looking like this:

File "command-696969696969696", line 4   df.write 
^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

What I'm wondering is if I can get the cell header or any kind of information about the cell from the "command id" or whatever "command-696969696969696" is representing